# Datatables not correctly reading JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, datatable

So I looked around and couldn't find anyone having the issues I am having right now.  I have using Jquery Datatables and filling this datatable using JSON i recieve from an ajax call.  I keep getting the tn 4 error which means I have an unknown parameter. https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4. But I do not see why this is happening! I am going to try and give as much detail as possible to see if someone can help me solve this annoying problem!

This is is the exact error code I am recieving.

> DataTables warning: table id = manageUsersTable - Requested unknown parameter 'CONCAT(E.FNAME, '', E.LNAME)' for row 0.  For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn.4

This is my PHP Query:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT CONCAT(E.FNAME, ' ', E.LNAME), CONCAT(M.FNAME, ' ', M.LNAME), E.ISTERMINATED FROM EMPLOYEE E INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE M ON M.ID = E.SUPERVISOR;")
```

This is the javasript that initializes the datatable:

```
manageUsersTable = $('#manageUsersTable').dataTable({
    "responsive": true,
    "sAjaxDataProp": "",
    "sAjaxSource": "all_emps.php",
    "aoColumns":[
        { "mData": "CONCAT(E.FNAME, ' ', E.LNAME)"},
        { "mData": "CONCAT(M.FNAME, ' ', M.LNAME)"},
        { "mData": "ISTERMINATED"}
    ]
});  
$('#manageUsersTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        manageUsersTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

I have an ajax call that I use to look at the data by doing a console.log and here is that call.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'all_emps.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);   
        }
});
```

and here is the JSON value I see:

```js
[{"CONCAT(E.FNAME, ' ', E.LNAME)":"John Paul","CONCAT(M.FNAME, ' ', M.LNAME)":"Bob Saget","ISTERMINATED":"Employed"},{"CONCAT(E.FNAME, ' ', E.LNAME)":"Jim Bob","CONCAT(M.FNAME, ' ', M.LNAME)":"Bob Saget","ISTERMINATED":"Employed"},{"CONCAT(E.FNAME, ' ', E.LNAME)":"Saget Bob","CONCAT(M.FNAME, ' ', M.LNAME)":"Bobbity Saget","ISTERMINATED":"Employed"},{"CONCAT(E.FNAME, ' ', E.LNAME)":"Sagetty Bob","CONCAT(M.FNAME, ' ', M.LNAME)":"Bob Sagetry","ISTERMINATED":"Employed"},{"CONCAT(E.FNAME, ' ', E.LNAME)":"Sagetry Bob","CONCAT(M.FNAME, ' ', M.LNAME)":"Wilbur Wright","ISTERMINATED":"Employed"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases instead for your database function fields

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT CONCAT(E.FNAME, ' ', E.LNAME) as ENAME, CONCAT(M.FNAME, ' ', M.LNAME) as MNAME, E.ISTERMINATED FROM EMPLOYEE E INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE M ON M.ID = E.SUPERVISOR;")
```

And use those names in your datatables column defs

```
"aoColumns":[
    { "mData": "ENAME"},
    { "mData": "MNAME"},
    { "mData": "ISTERMINATED"}
]
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked perfectly! I would upvote but I am lame and I do not have 15 rep lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try aliasing your CONCAT() statements.

```
SELECT CONCAT(E.FNAME, ' ', E.LNAME) AS name1, etc...
```